# How to use "top" command with interactive option 1 (for many cores) on Android?

Tags: android

On Linux, when we use "top" we can switch to see different cores with interactive option "1".

How to use "top" command with interactive option 1 (for many cores) on Android?

Comment: Use `top 1` to pass the command.

Comment: Does this work on Android?

Comment: I also tried on Linux. I got :

 top: unknown argument '1'
usage: top -hv | -abcHimMsS -d delay -n iterations [-u user | -U user] -p pid [,pid ...]

Comment: We must have different versions, I get `top -hv | -bcEHiOSs1 -d secs -n max -u|U user -p pid(s) -o field -w [cols]`. Does Android even have top?

Comment: My Android has top but not the interactive '1' option.